# Automatically do capture screen daily on a website

Tags: automation, screenshot

Is there any tool/scripts can do a capture screen on a webpage daily (DJI line daily line chart)? Since the site only keeps today's data.

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer on StackExchange Software Recommendations, https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found [SiteShooter](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/web_site_screenshot.html) resolved my problem.

Answer (score 8):

**[Web Screen Capture](http://www.webscreencapture.com/)** will automatically capture a web page if you run a batch file with the following command as a [scheduled task](http://www.iopus.com/guides/winscheduler.htm):

```
webscreencapture.exe [url] [image]
```

> Web Screen Capture is a free web site
>   and web page screenshot and thumbnail
>   software, it can take screenshots of
>   web pages and save them as full sized
>   images, and the images can be output
>   in the JPG/JPEG, BMP, PNG, or GIF
>   formats. The image's Pixel Format can
>   be changed.

Main Features:

- Create full size screenshots of website pages.
- Supports JPG, GIF, PNG, BMP image formats.
- Supports **command line usage**.
- Supports batch convert with command line.
- Simple, very fast and easy-to-use.
- Freeware, not paid for use.

Comment: That's quite an inventive solution ;-) Though how do I set up a scheduled task?

Comment: @Ivo - How to use the Windows Task Scheduler (with screen shots): http://www.iopus.com/guides/winscheduler.htm

Comment: I knew you would edit it :D Thanks for the update!

Comment: @Ivo - I knew you were teasing me. :)

Comment: @Molly, thank you for your detailed answer. However, webscreencapture can't capture this flash object in this site. (http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=%5EDJI#symbol=%5EDJI;range=1d;ohlcvalues=0). So I still have to manually use 'picpick' do capture. Is there any work around? Thanks!!

Comment: @Stan - with flash, i'm afraid so ... i tried WebShots, same problem

Comment: Link is dead - presumably this tool isn't available any more.

Answer (score 1):

**[Pagescreen](https://pagescreen.io/)** offers to take a daily (or hourly/weekly) HD capture of a given web page - directly from the online service, or using its RESTful API. It can also alert you of any website visual change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Agenty web scraping tool to capture full page, or visible page screenshot and automatically upload to your S3 bucket as well.

Here are docs - https://www.agenty.com/docs/scraping-agent/web-scraping-with-screenshot

And example full page screenshot on pinterest - https://www.pinterest.com/pin/486740672227404017

**Disclosure** - I am the founder of Agenty

Answer (score 0):

[Snapchive](https://snapchive.com/) allows you to automatically take a screenshot every day/week/month of any website you want. It let's you choose the image format you want to save the image as, and also supports taking screenshots from multiple devices.

It will notify you when each screenshot is taken and will let you download them.